# Getting single place details from google_place gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, google-places

I'm creating an app that uses google_places gem and what I want to do is to search hotels and restaurants close to chosen location. Google_places gem helped me a lot, but all it shows is something like:

> [#
>
> @place_id="ChIJl6wYnDyG_UYRLHo26ttMYf0", @vicinity="48",
>   @lat=54.1847303, @lng=18.432423,
>   @viewport={"northeast"=>{"lat"=>54.1833813197085,
>   "lng"=>18.1291523802915}, "southwest"=>{"lat"=>54.1833813197085,
>   "lng"=>18.12645441970849}}, @name="Polando no name",
>   @icon="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",

Can I do something to display normally name and e.g. latitude? All I have is:

> @types=["restaurant", "food", "point_of_interest", "establishment"],
>
> <%= @client.spots(@trip.latitude, @trip.longitude, :radius => 100,
>   :types => ['hotel','sleep'], detail: true) %

I couldn't find anything helpful in google_places gem repository and google, so I decided to write it here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided contradicts your title so I'll try to answer both:

In your controller, if you have, `@spots = @client.spots(@trip.latitude, @trip.longitude, :radius => 100, :types => ['hotel','sleep'], detail: true)`

you should be able to iterate through `@spots` in your view.

```
<% @spots.each do |spot| %>
  <%= spot.name %>
<% end %>
```

When in doubt, hit `#methods` (such as `spot.methods`) and that will give you some insight as to what you can do with `spot` — or any object.

Answer (score 0):

There is a function **getDetails(...)** of *Google API* that returns more information about some place, extending the one returned by the **nearbySearch(...)** function.

```
var SearchPlaces = {
    GPMHotels: ['hotel']
    , GPMFoodPlaces: ['restaurant']
    , GPMShoppingPlaces: ['shopping_mall']
};

var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(GPMap);

function SearchGPMapServiceNearPlacesFn(service) {
    function GetHTML(place) {
        var distance = "";
        if (place.geometry && place.geometry.location) {
            var fromLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(GPMapLocation.lat, GPMapLocation.lng);
            distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(fromLatLng, place.geometry.location);
            distance = Math.ceil(distance).toLocaleString('@languaje');
        }
        var html = "*&nbsp;" + (distance ? distance + " m. " : "") + place.name + ".&nbsp;&nbsp;"
                       + place.formatted_address + ".&nbsp;&nbsp;" +
            (place.international_phone_number || "");
        return html;
    }

    function GetPlaceDetails(place_id) {
        if (!place_id) return;
        service.getDetails({
            placeId: place_id
        }, function (place, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                //-->> console.log({ fn: 'GetPlaceDetails', item: place });
                $("#GPMNearSitesList").append($('<li>').html(GetHTML(place)));
            }
        });
    }

    service.nearbySearch({
        location: GPMapLocation,
        radius: GPMapOptions.searchRadiusList,
    },
    function (results, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                GetPlaceDetails(results[i].place_id);
                //-->>console.log({ fn: "SearchGPMapServiceNearPlacesFn", item: results[i] });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

See: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-details